# Node JS - How to retrieve a result from a query in a async function?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await

Node js -
Please could you help me to figure out how to retrieve a value from a query, inside an async function?
The async function will take one parameter as input; and the sql result should be the output.

I've tried the code below but it provides 'undefined' as a result.
I'm using MSSQL db.

Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
getId('Justin')
.then( (mydata)=>{ console.log(mydata) } ); //I hope it to display the id of 'Justin'. But instead, it returns undefined

async function getId(inputName){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config); //ok
        await pool.request()
        .input('inputName',   inputName )
        .query(  'select id from mytable where inputName = @inputName' , (err,result)=>{
            console.log (result.recordset[0].id); //here it works. it can display the id
            return result.recordset[0].id; // but I could not return the id from here.
        } )

    }
    catch(err){console.log(err)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert it into a `Promise`.

The `Promise` object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation and its resulting value.

```
function getId(inputName) {
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) {
  try {
   let pool = await sql.connect(config); //ok
   await pool.request()
    .input('inputName', inputName)
    .query('select id from mytable where inputName = @inputName', (err, result) => {
     return resolve(result.recordset[0].id); // return id from here
    })

  } catch (err) {
   reject(err)
  }
 })
}

getId('Justin')
 .then((mydata) => {
  console.log(mydata)
 });
```